# Wrong parentheses size in \binom with xelatex and unicode-math in displaystyle

Tags: xetex, amsmath, unicode-math, delimiters, displaystyle

I am writing thesis, using XeLaTeX with `unicode-math`, documentclass is modified `memoir`. I need to typeset equations with binomial coefficient, however I get wrong sizes of parentheses around them.

And `unicode-math` seems to be ruining the output of `\binom`, `\choose`,
`\genfrac`, etc.

When I do:

```
$$\binom{n}{k}\qquad \tbinom{n}{k} \qquad \dbinom{n}{k}$$
$$\binom{5}{6}\qquad \tbinom{5}{6} \qquad \dbinom{5}{6}$$
```

I get binomial coefficient with too small parentheses around it:

[image: Binomials with wrong parentheses sizes]

I’ve tried `renewcommand`ing `binom` by:

```
\renewcommand{\binom}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
```

with no success, however placing it between `\left(` and `\right)` gives correct bigger parentheses.

I have set non-standard fonts (see below), but disabling them doesn’t change this.

Using `{n \choose k}` gives the very same output… How to overcome this problem?

Minimal code generating this is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,unicode-math,xltxtra}

% Those are needed to use same fonts as I do.
% Parentheses are strange even without them
%\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
%\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
%\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}
%\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,num,Greek,greek}]{Linux Libertine O Italic}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,num,Greek,greek}]{Linux Libertine O}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{latin,Latin,num,Greek,greek}]{Linux Libertine O Bold}
%\setmathfont[range={"221E}]{Linux Libertine O}% "0221E = \infty

\begin{document}

$$\binom{n}{k}\qquad \tbinom{n}{k} \qquad \dbinom{n}{k}$$
$$\binom{5}{6}\qquad \tbinom{5}{6} \qquad \dbinom{5}{6}$$

\end{document}
```

EDIT: **Simple working workaround**

Redefining `\binom` this way makes it look acceptably, at least for my set of fonts:

```
\renewcommand{\dbinom}[2]{\left(\!\!\begin{array}{c}{#1} \\ {#2} \end{array}\!\!\right)}
\let\oldbinom\binom
\renewcommand{\binom}[2]{\mathchoice{\dbinom{#1}{#2}}{\oldbinom{#1}{#2}}{\oldbinom{#1}{#2}}{\oldbinom{#1}{#2}}}
```

Comment: Temporary workaround – use `\renewcommand{\dbinom}[2]{\left(\!\!\begin{array}{c}{#1} \\ {#2} \end{array}\!\!\right)}` every time in displaystyle, instead of `\binom`.

Comment: *Temporary workaround* should be just redefine the `\binom` macro, rather than redefine `\dbinom` and then change the code. Look at `\mathpalette` and `\mathchoice`. Plus, I've always had problems with the fences in `\binom`… in any compiler.

Comment: Thanks. Now my workaround looks like this:
`\renewcommand{\dbinom}[2]{\left(\!\!\begin{array}{c}{#1} \\ {#2} \end{array}\!\!\right)}
\let\oldbinom\binom
\renewcommand{\binom}[2]{\mathchoice{\dbinom{#1}{#2}}{\oldbinom{#1}{#2}}{\oldbinom{#1}{#2}}{\oldbinom{#1}{#2}}}`
Works good, with regular `\binom` in displaystyle. :) (added it to question, maybe will help somebody later)

Comment: My proposition was not to redefine `\dbinom`. For instance just `\renewcommand*\binom[2]{\mathchoice {\left(\!\!\begin{array}{c}{#1}\\{#2}\end{array}\!\!\right)} {\oldbinom{#1}{#2}} {\oldbinom{#1}{#2}} {\oldbinom{#1}{#2}}}`. Until someone comes to solve this :)

Comment: Yes I understood it, but `\dbinom` worked wrongly anyway, so it seemed easier for me to redefine it and use it in new `\binom`. This way the workaround works for two commands.

Comment: I should probably also set `\displaystyle` in `\dbinom`… But array seems to force it anyway.

Comment: the stix fonts, on which `unicode-math` is based, are still beta, and there are some problems that have come up in testing; one such problem is the sizing of delimiters in matrices and `\binom`.  this is being worked on.

Comment: the sizing of delimiters in `\binom` and friends is dependent on two parameters which have no counterparts in the otf (opentype font) math table.  this is being studied now; it is not an easy problem to solve or work around.  the two "obvious" approaches are (1) change the tex program (not going to happen) or (2) upgrade the otf math table (serious political difficulties).  so, for the moment, on hold.

Comment: `$$ .. $$` should not be used for maths in 2e should it? @barbarabeeton ? (I realise this isn't the problem - just by the by.)

Comment: @cfr -- true that `$$ ... $$` shouldn't be used for display math.  i did ignore that in my comments, since the problem of whether the stix fonts are going to be usable with (la)tex is of much greater concern to me.  (i've been working on that project for 20 years now, and the thought that it might fail is devastating.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Is that really likely? From your explanation, I gather this would apply to all opentype maths fonts and not just STIX? (Even Latin Modern Math?) That would be ... appalling - and I haven't been working on it for 20 years!

Comment: Well, I did not use `$$` in the thesis, in which the problem occurred, and used it only for the sake of the simplicity of the example. But, anyway, good to know it should be avoided (I’ve just read on the reasons for it), thanks. :) And the thesis is in Polish, and can be seen here: http://kofeina.net/~benek/studia/praca_magisterska_benedykt_jaworski.pdf

Answer (score 8):

The `unicode-math` and `stix`/`xits` fonts are natively OpenType fonts.
Setting of math is accomplished by means of parameters provided by the
OTF math table.

The OpenType mechanism was a creation of Microsoft.  The math table,
although it is based largely on the mechanism used by TeX, as
described in appendix G of the TeXbook, lacks two of the font
parameters required by TeX, `sigma20` and `sigma21`, whose use is
defined in rule 15e on p.445.  The primitives `\overwithdelims`,
`\atopwithdelims` and `\abovewithdelims` require appropriate
settings of these parameters in order to work properly.

Ulrik Vieth reported on the absence of these two parameters in his talk,
"[OpenType Math
Illuminated](http://tug.org/~vieth/papers/bachotex2009/ot-math-talk.pdf)",
presented at BachoTeX 2009; the reference is on p.19 of the slides.

These primitives wrap delimiters (usually a matched pair of parentheses,
brackets or braces, but there are other possibilities) around a
"generalized fraction", a vertically aligned pair of symbols with or
without a fraction line.  They are the structure on which the `amsmath`
commands `\binom` and others using `\genfrac` are based.  There is no
other "native" mechanism for setting such delimiters with any TeX engine.

Although the absence of these parameters has been known for some time,
only relatively recently has the extremely serious nature of the
implications of their absence become widely obvious, with near-final
testing of the `stix` fonts.

This is not an easy problem to solve or work around.  The two
"obvious" approaches are (1) change the TeX program (not going to happen),
or (2) upgrade the OTF math table.  There are serious "political"
difficulties involved in implementing the second approach.
So, for the moment, proper correction of this flaw is on hold.

Comment: This is, as I said above, appalling. The idea that the project might fail due to "political" difficulties is, frankly, beyond ... well, not beyond belief, unfortunately. But beyond the pale, certainly.

Comment: @cfr -- we've presented the facts and implications to the individuals we know, who might be able to get something done, and are hoping for the best.  i'm not in charge of the project or decisions; i'm doing what i can to provide accurate information and arguments that i hope will be compelling.  to say that this is a huge disappointment is a vast understatement.

Comment: Yes, I know. I certainly wasn't suggesting you were implicated! (I'm not sure from your comment if you thought this, but just in case.)

Comment: The luatex manual suggest open type names for sigma20 (delim1) `FractionDelimiterDisplayStyleSize` and sigma21 (delim2) `FractionDelimiterSize` and when an open type math font is loaded luatex seems to try to set the relevant `\Umathfractiondelsize` (and one could adapt it).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes but see note 9 :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I saw the note, but as luatex doesn't rely on the value existing in the font one can "correct" the font.

Comment: IMHO, the XeTeX or LuaTeX engine can initialize the delim1 and delim2 parameter to very good value if they take all others parameters from MATH table. They can construct a virtual \atop with typical values above and below (something like phantom) and measure such result and use it as delim1 and delim2. This can be done only once when Unicode math font is loaded. I tested this today (2020). LuaTeX sets delim1 too big and XeTeX too small. Fontforge suggests very good value, see menu: Element / Font info, tab: TeX, select: TeX math symbol, click:  "more params".

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

The implementation of `\genfrac` (and so `\binom`) has been altered in Unicode TeXs in the `2016-11-05 amsmath.dtx 2.16a` release of `amsmath` and the example in the question now produces

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$\binom{n}{k}\qquad \tbinom{n}{k} \qquad \dbinom{n}{k}$$
$$\binom{5}{6}\qquad \tbinom{5}{6} \qquad \dbinom{5}{6}$$
\end{document}
```

The code in `amsmath` is basically following the outline sketched in the answer below.

---

**Original Answer**

An updated version more closely matching the tighter spacing and larger minimum size of generalised fraction brackets is given by the following, which may be run with pdftex or xetex, to compare using lm fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,a4paper]{article}

\addtolength\textwidth{40pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ifx\Umathchar\undefined
\usepackage{lmodern}
\else
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\fi


\makeatletter
\ifx\Umathcode\@undefined\else

\DeclareRobustCommand{\genfrac}[6]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1#2}%
  \edef\@tempb{\@nx\@genfrac\@mathstyle{#4}%
    % just \over or \above never withdelims versions
    \ifx @#3@\@@over\else\@@above\fi 
    }%
\ifx\@tempa\@empty \else
\bgroup % so mathord not mathinner
\left\ifx\relax#1\relax.\else#1\fi % assumes . is null delimiter 
                                   % otherwise add specified delimiter
\kern-\nulldelimiterspace % fractions add extra nulldelimiter space
\fi
  \@tempb{#3}{\mathstrut{#5}}{\mathstrut{#6}}%
\ifx\@tempa\@empty \else
\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\right\ifx\relax#2\relax.\else#2\fi
\egroup
\fi
}
\fi
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\[\binom{n}{k}\qquad \tbinom{n}{k} \qquad \dbinom{n}{k}\]
\[\binom{5}{6}\qquad \tbinom{5}{6} \qquad \dbinom{5}{6}\]
\[ 2^k-\binom{k}{1}2^{k-1}+\binom{k}{2}2^{k-2}\]
\[\sum_i\left[\binom{n_1}{i}
    \binom{n_2}{n_3-n_1+i}\binom{n_3}{n_3-n_2+i} + \binom{n_1-1}{i}
    \binom{n_2-1}{n_3-n_1+i} \binom{n_3-1}{n_3-n_2+i}\right]\]
\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer:**

If you want to use `\left`/`\right` I don't think you need an array and `\mathchoice` just use `\atop` or `\over` without the delimiters, then wrap in left/right pair.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{memoir}


\usepackage{amsmath,unicode-math,xltxtra}

% Those are needed to use same fonts as I do.
% Parentheses are strange even without them
%\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
%\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ubuntu}
%\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}
%\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,num,Greek,greek}]{Linux Libertine O Italic}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,num,Greek,greek}]{Linux Libertine O}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{latin,Latin,num,Greek,greek}]{Linux Libertine O Bold}
%\setmathfont[range={"221E}]{Linux Libertine O}% "0221E = \infty

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\genfrac}[6]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1#2}%
  \edef\@tempb{\@nx\@genfrac\@mathstyle{#4}%
    \csname @@\ifx @#3@over\else above\fi
    \endcsname
    }%
\ifx\@tempa\@empty \else
\left\ifx\relax#1\relax.\else#1\fi
\fi
  \@tempb{#3}{#5}{#6}%
\ifx\@tempa\@empty \else
\right\ifx\relax#2\relax.\else#2\fi
\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$$\binom{n}{k}\qquad \tbinom{n}{k} \qquad \dbinom{n}{k}$$
$$\binom{5}{6}\qquad \tbinom{5}{6} \qquad \dbinom{5}{6}$$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With lualatex this is not an unsolvable problem. It tries to give the two missing parameters sensible values (and it if fails one can adapt them):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\[\binom{n}{k}\qquad \tbinom{n}{k} \qquad \dbinom{n}{k}\]

\Umathfractiondelsize\displaystyle=40pt
\Umathfractiondelsize\textstyle=40pt

\[\binom{n}{k}\qquad \tbinom{n}{k} \qquad \dbinom{n}{k}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could make a feature request for xelatex that it add something similar too.