# Value of LuaTeX’s \mathstyle in \frac (de)nominator

Tags: luatex, boxes

> This was fixed in version from 2017/06/15 (available on CTAN).

This is a followup question of [How to transfer math style in \hbox_set?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369604/4918).

While the code I posted there as an answer using LuaTeX’s `\mathstyle` primitive it doesn’t work inside of the (de)nominator of a `\frac`. If a `\frac` happens to appear in `\textstyle` the (de)nominator actually is set in `\scriptstyle` (as far as I can tell), but `\mathstyle` stell equals 2.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = luatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip,xparse,xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,lualatex-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter

\cs_new:Npn \tobi_save_math_style: {
   \int_case:nn { \mathstyle } {
      { \displaystyle } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \displaystyle } }
      { \textstyle } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \textstyle } }
      { \scriptstyle } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \scriptstyle } }
      { \scriptscriptstyle } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \scriptscriptstyle } }
   }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \boxtest }{ m }{
   \mode_if_math:TF {
      % aktuellen Mathemodus ermitteln und für später sichen
      \tobi_save_math_style:
      % Box mit entsprechender Formel speichern
      \hbox_gset:Nn \l_tmpa_box {
         \begingroup
            \(
               \m@th
               \tl_use:N \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl
               #1
            \)
         \endgroup
      }
   } {
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
   }
   \fbox { \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box }
   [\tl_to_str:n { \mathstyle } = \mathstyle; saved style = \tl_to_str:N \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl] % for testing!
}

\cs_new:Npn \tobi_genfrac:nnnn #1#2#3#4 {
%   \colorlet { l_tobi_current_color_before_frac } { . }
%   \begingroup
%      \color { #2 }
      \genfrac { } { } { } { #1 } {
%         \color { l_tobi_current_color_before_frac }
         #3
      } {
%         \color { l_tobi_current_color_before_frac }
         #4
      }
%   \endgroup
}

\RenewDocumentCommand { \frac } { O{.} m m } {
   \tobi_genfrac:nnnn { } { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
}

\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

OK: $a^2 = a^{\boxtest{2}}$

OK: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} = \frac{\boxtest{1}}{2}$

OK: $\frac{1}{2} = \boxtest{\frac{1}{2}}$

OK: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} = \boxtest{\frac{1}{2}}$

wrong: $\frac{1}{2} \neq \frac{\boxtest{1}}{2}$

wrong: $\genfrac{}{}{}{}{1}{2} \neq \genfrac{}{}{}{}{\boxtest{1}}{2}$

\end{document}
```

So … is it possible to capture the correct style in this case too?

**Update:** I added an example using `\genfrac`, which is used in my real document do get a coloured fraction line.

Comment: With the newest lualatex-math the genfrac-examples look ok.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Indeed, there was a [fix](https://github.com/phst/lualatex-math/issues/20) some days ago. But I forgot to mention it here … I’ll add a note to the question …

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\frac{a}{b}` is essentially `{a \over b}` and the big problem with the infix `\over` is that it makes tracking the current style hard luatex does not change that.

to get a version in which `\mathstyle` is set you need `\Ustack{a \over b}`  so in latex you would have to redefine `\frac` and related commands to use `\Ustack`.

One possibility would be to load `lualatex-math` which redefines `\frac` in this way.

Comment: Hi, thanks with the package it works, but unfortunately not in my real document: I redefine `\frac` using `\genfrac` and the `luatex-math` manual says it works with `\genfrac` but it doesn’t … (see my OP for example code)

Comment: @Tobi Look at the code of `\genfrac` and alter that command. Or paste the definition with the added `\Ustack` in `\tobi_genfrac:nnn`.

Comment: @Tobi possibly because amsmath now uses a completely different implementation of genfrac when used with luatex or xetex, just take the definition from amsmath and add Ustack

Comment: Thanks I’ll try it. But shouldn’t be `lualatex-math` made compatible or at least not state that it’s compatible …?!

Comment: Great. I don’t even have to add `\Ustack`. It is totally fine, if I just copy the “classic version” (`amsmath.dtx`, ll. 611-616) of `\genfrac` in my document.

Comment: @Tobi the classic version does not work in luatex unless you set the additional font parameters, and doesn't work at all in xetex. that's why I changed it.

Comment: What could be symptoms of “doesn't work”? In my test document I can't find anything wrong …

Comment: @Tobi The brackets do not grow (correctly or at all, depending on the exact font setup used) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328222/1090

Comment: Aha. Could you please take a look at my solution and check if it’s correct? :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with …

```
% !TeX program = luatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip,xparse,xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,lualatex-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter

\cs_new:Npn \tobi_save_math_style: {
   \int_case:nn { \mathstyle } {
      { \displaystyle             } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \displaystyle             } }
      { \crampeddisplaystyle      } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \crampeddisplaystyle      } }
      { \textstyle                } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \textstyle                } }
      { \crampedtextstyle         } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \crampedtextstyle         } }
      { \scriptstyle              } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \scriptstyle              } }
      { \crampedscriptstyle       } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \crampedscriptstyle       } }
      { \scriptscriptstyle        } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \scriptscriptstyle        } }
      { \crampedscriptscriptstyle } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl { \crampedscriptscriptstyle } }
   }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \boxtest }{ m }{
   \mode_if_math:TF {
      % aktuellen Mathemodus ermitteln und für später sichen
      \tobi_save_math_style:
      % Box mit entsprechender Formel speichern
      \hbox_gset:Nn \l_tmpa_box {
         \begingroup
            \(
               \m@th
               \tl_use:N \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl
               #1
            \)
         \endgroup
      }
   } {
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #1 }
   }
   \fbox { \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box }
%   [\tl_to_str:n { \mathstyle } = \mathstyle; saved style = \tl_to_str:N \l_tobi_saved_math_style_tl] % for testing!
}

% from amsmath.dtx, ll. 696--701
\DeclareRobustCommand{\genfrac}[6]{{%
\@mathstyle{#4}%
\genfrac@choice o{#1}%
{\Ustack{\begingroup#5\endgroup\ifx @#3@\@@over\else\@@above\fi#3\relax#6}}%
\genfrac@choice c{#2}%
}}

\cs_new:Npn \tobi_genfrac:nnnn #1#2#3#4 {
%   \colorlet { l_tobi_current_color_before_frac } { . }
%   \begingroup
%      \color { #2 }
      \genfrac { } { } { } { #1 } {
%         \color { l_tobi_current_color_before_frac }
         #3
      } {
%         \color { l_tobi_current_color_before_frac }
         #4
      }
%   \endgroup
}

\RenewDocumentCommand { \frac } { O{.} m m } {
   \tobi_genfrac:nnnn { } { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.3pt}

\makeatother\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

OK: $a^2 = a^{\boxtest{2}}$

OK: $a^{2^2} = a^{2^{\boxtest{2}}}$

OK: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} = \frac{\boxtest{1}}{2}$

OK: $\frac{1}{2} = \boxtest{\frac{1}{2}}$

OK: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} = \boxtest{\frac{1}{2}}$

OK: $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{\boxtest{1}}{2}$

OK: $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{\boxtest{2}}$

OK: $\genfrac{}{}{}{}{1}{2} = \genfrac{}{}{}{}{\boxtest{1}}{2}$

OK: $\binom{1}{2} = \binom{\boxtest{1}}{2}$

OK: $\binom{1}{2} = \binom{1}{\boxtest{2}}$

OK: $\displaystyle\binom{1}{2} = \binom{\boxtest{1}}{2}$

OK: $\displaystyle\binom{1}{2} = \binom{1}{\boxtest{2}}$

OK: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty = \sum_{\boxtest{n=1}}^{\boxtest{\infty}}$

OK: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty = \sum_{\boxtest{n=1}}^{\boxtest{\infty}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes ustack looks to be added in about the right place. At some point may consider adding Ustack in amsmath generally under luatex but for now you should probably raise an issue at https://github.com/phst/lualatex-math/issues and point out that "someone" changed amsmath under the package and so broke the patch that it does to genfrac to add Ustack.

Comment: Allright … [done](https://github.com/phst/lualatex-math/issues/20) :-)