# Overly large parentheses for binomial coefficient with mtpro2

Tags: amsmath, delimiters, mtpro

Using the lite (or complete) version of `mtpro2` results in binomial coefficient with overly large parentheses. How to fix it? The ideal solution should work in inline math as well as in subscript and second-order subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
Binomial coefficient has overly large parentheses in \verb|mtpro2|
``lite'':
\[
\begin{gathered}
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! \, (n-k)!}
             = \left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{n}{k}\right)
             = \biggl(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{n}{k}\biggr), \\
\binom{k+\ell}{j}
             = \left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{k+\ell}{j}\right)
             = \biggl(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{k+\ell}{j}\biggr).
\end{gathered}
\]
A \verb|\left...\right| pair is not ideal since the delimiters may
change their sizes, depending on whether the content has ascenders
and/or descenders. A \verb|\biggl...\biggr| pair seems just right.
\end{document}
```

> [image: binomial coefficient]

Possibly related posts:

- [Wrong parentheses size in \binom with xelatex and unicode-math in displaystyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269980). But `mtpro2` is *not* OpenType math font, so `\fontdimen20` and `\fontdimen21` from family 2 should be available.
- [Strange behaviour of binomial coefficient's delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137141). But `mtpro2` already makes its math extension font scalable (see `mtpro2.dtx` for the line `\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}{<->mt2exa}{}`).

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the parentheses really look way too large. Luckily one can use the same code as your third binom to adjust the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}


\newcommand{\mybinom}[2]{\biggl(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}\biggr)}
\everydisplay{\let\binom\mybinom}



\begin{document}
Binomial coefficient has overly large parentheses in \verb|mtpro2|
``lite'':
\[
\begin{gathered}
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! \, (n-k)!}
             = \left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{n}{k}\right)
             = \biggl(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{n}{k}\biggr), \\
\binom{k+\ell}{j}
             = \left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{k+\ell}{j}\right)
             = \biggl(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{k+\ell}{j}\biggr).
\end{gathered}
\]
A \verb|\left...\right| pair is not ideal since the delimiters may
change their sizes, depending on whether the content has ascenders
and/or descenders. A \verb|\biggl...\biggr| pair seems just right.

$\binom{n}{k}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This breaks inline math though :(

Comment: @RuixiZhang repaired

Answer (score 1):

We can modify `\fontdimen20` in the math symbol font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

% Alter \fontdimen20 in the math symbol font
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}{%
  <-7> mt2syf
  <7-9> mt2sys
  <9-> mt2syt
}{% Default is 2.39. We change it to 2.38
  \fontdimen20\font=2.38\fontdimen6\font
}

\begin{document}
Binomial coefficient has overly large parentheses in \verb|mtpro2|
``lite'':
\[
\begin{gathered}
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! \, (n-k)!}
             = \left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{n}{k}\right)
             = \biggl(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{n}{k}\biggr), \\
\binom{k+\ell}{j}
             = \left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{k+\ell}{j}\right)
             = \biggl(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{k+\ell}{j}\biggr).
\end{gathered}
\]
A \verb|\left...\right| pair is not ideal since the delimiters may
change their sizes, depending on whether the content has ascenders
and/or descenders. A \verb|\biggl...\biggr| pair seems just right.
\end{document}
```

> [image: better binom]
>   Note the better spacing to the `\biggl( \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{...}{...} \biggr)` construct.

---

### Explanations

Everything should have worked if TeX allowed more than 16 different heights/depths in one TFM file.

When TeX is constructing a “generalized fraction” with delimiters, it follows Rule 15e in Appendix G of *The TeXbook*:

> **[Rule] 15e.** Enclose the vbox that was constructed in Rule 15c or 15d by delimiters whose height plus depth is at least <sub>20</sub>, if  > […]

On the one hand, if we run, on a command line, `tftopl mt2syt.tfm mt2syt.pl` and then inspect the font dimension parameter 20 in the `mt2syt.pl` file of the math symbol font, we find

```
(FAMILY MT2SYT)
...
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   ...
   (PARAMETER D 20 R 2.39)
   ...
   )
...
```

On the other hand, the math extension font `mt2exa` **does include delimiters designed at size 2.4**, namely, the `\bigg` ones. So there must be something causing TeX to skip size 2.4 and pick size 3.0, the latter being the overly large `\Bigg` ones.

Indeed, after running `tftopl mt2exa.tfm mt2exa.pl`, we find out what *really* happen to the `\bigg` delimiters:

```
(FAMILY M2TEXA)
...
(CHARACTER O 22 % <- This is the \bigg left parenthesis, with glyph size 2.4
   (CHARWD R 0.675)
   (CHARHT R 0.046)
   (CHARDP R 2.337999)
   (NEXTLARGER O 40)
   )
...
```

TeX knows nothing about the actual glyph. It only knows the dimensions of the “bounding box” supplied by the TFM file. To TeX, the `\bigg` delimiters are only `0.046 + 2.337999 = 2.383999` units tall, which is less than `2.39`. Therefore, TeX must choose the next larger ones. The depth shown above should have been `2.354`, not `2.337999`, and this is likely caused during metric conversion when TeX tries to round-off certain depths to keep the total number under 16.

A simple solution is thus to modify `\fontdimen20` from `2.39` to `2.38`.