# Loading `xits-math.otf` for certain characters messes with spacing of fractions and binomial coefficients

Tags: fonts, spacing, unicode-math

Today I witnessed some odd behaviour: Using

```
\setmathfont[range={\rightrightarrows}]{xits-math.otf}
```

to load the symbol ⇉ changes the spacing of the `\binom` and `\frac` command. Here is how it looks without that command:

[image]

And with that command, it looks like

[image]

So it's especially cumbersome with `\tbinom`. Anyone has a clue what is going on?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{libertinusmath-regular.otf}

% remove this
\setmathfont[range={\rightrightarrows}]{xits-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\[
    \binom a b
    \quad
    \tbinom a b
    \quad
    \frac a b
    \quad
    \tfrac a b
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the same problem treated here: [Wrong parentheses size in `\binom` with xelatex and unicode-math in `displaystyle`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269980)

Comment: @barbarabeeton So does this affect *every* OTF font? Why does it work with libertinus-math, which is also OTF?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, some developers have devised methods that don't require dependence on the "missing" attribute.  I don't have personal experience with any fonts other than stix.  There was a discussion about the problem last year in a forum on the AMS web site; unfortunately, since my retirement, I have lost access to the forum, and a search on the site doesn't uncover any clues to its location.

Answer (score 1):

The last loaded math font sets the parameters. Load again Libertinus Math. (Note: I had to change the font name for XITS Math.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{libertinusmath-regular.otf}

\setmathfont[range={\rightrightarrows}]{XITSMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{libertinusmath-regular.otf}

\begin{document}
\[
    \binom a b
    \quad
    \tbinom a b
    \quad
    \frac a b
    \quad
    \tfrac a b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]