# Binomial coefficient parentheses are inconsistent across engines

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex

Using the following code (run pdfLaTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX), pdfTeX and XeTeX produce identical binomial coefficients, but LuaTeX makes larger parentheses in `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`. Are these discrepancies by design, or are these engine-related bugs? How can I obtain unified results?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\baselineskip=18pt

\ifx\directlua\undefined
  \ifx\XeTeXcharclass\undefined
    pdf\/TeX%
  \else
    XeTeX%
  \fi
\else
    LuaTeX%
\fi

$\displaystyle      {n\choose k},
 \textstyle         {n\choose k},
 \scriptstyle       {n\choose k},
 \scriptscriptstyle {n\choose k}$
\end{document}
```

[image: pdfTeX]

[image: XeTeX]

[image: LuaTeX]

Comment: I have a feeling I saw this when working on the opentype version (as in the related gh issue) can't remember what the outcome was though...

Comment: @davidcarlisle It's very strange indeed. In the gh issue I opened, the exact opposite happened; that is, LuaTeX chose a smaller size. I don't have more time to investigate though…

Comment: Potentially related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269980/218142

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL That post is definitely related to this post (lol), and in fact is an on-going issue (reported recently here https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/432). The post you mentioned was about *OpenType* math font (Cambria Math of Microsoft, for example), which TeX or pdfTeX cannot handle, while XeTeX and LuaTeX take *very* different approach to deal with. This post, however, is about TFM-based font (the standard Computer Modern), which should behave *exactly* the same across engines (but it doesn't, which makes it interesting).

Comment: I encountered the same problem with TeX Gyre DejaVu Math using LuaLaTeX. I worked around it using `\newcommand*{\valence}[2]{\ensuremath{\Bigl(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}\Bigr)}}`. Here I needed a command for tensor valence. I have no general solution but hopefully someone will. If it's helpful, I'm using `unicode-math` to set up my math fonts.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL well it's related but... that old post problem was because the classic tex implementation didn't work at all in unicode-math because opentype math has different font parameters. I re-implemented it in amsmath so it works better but in the gh issue 432 Ruixi Zhang suggests some improvements. If you are having issues in unicode-math try the variant in issue 432 But that doesn't affect the tfm version shown here where xetex and luatex might be expected to work like pdftex.

Comment: Ah well, sorry.